# Springboot examples with maven do not compile behind a proxy

Tags: java, spring, maven, proxy, spring-boot

I am studying spring and started running two examples: the first is the Java example at http://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/, the second is the web oriented at https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-mobile-web-content/. I work both at home and at office. At home I am directly connected to Internet, at office I have a NTLM proxy, with a CNTLM installation.
The first of the two examples  runs very well *both* at home and at work, having defined this settings.xml section:

```html
    <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    -->
    <proxy>
      <id>NTLM</id>
      <active>active</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>localhost</host>
      <port>3128</port>
    </proxy>
    </proxies>
```

The second one works well only at home, having also downloaded the code from github (to prevent "material" errors).
I have this error at compile time:

```html
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.1.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.1.10.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework:gs-serving-web-content:0.1.0 (/home/eugenioab/prj/gs-serving-web-content-master/initial/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.1.10.RELEASE from/to spring-milestone (https://repo.spring.io/libs-release): repo.spring.io: Nome o servizio sconosciuto and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 13: Unknown host repo.spring.io: Nome o servizio sconosciuto -> [Help 2]
```

Seems like the proxy configuration configuration in the settings.xml is not applied. This is the system configuration at work:

```html
eugenioab@UmbertII-HP-Z220-CMT-Workstation:~/prj$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T18:29:23+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/share/apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.7.0_75, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-24-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

TYA eugenio

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is this section:

```html
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>spring-releases</id>
    <name>Spring Releases</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>spring-releases</id>
    <name>Spring Releases</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Maybe the repositories are blocked in your company or something else. Try to remove these sections, so that the libs are loaded from Maven central (if you only use release versions, all artifacts should be available from there).

Comment: Many thanks. Tried also this, but did not work. I succeeded in building with gradle; building with maven gives the usual error. When running,  mvn bypasses my local proxy. In fact, tcpdump cannot see any traffic to and from my proxy at localhost:3128 (that is working for other maven based projects)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the proxy config in your settings.xml.

The  tag expects a boolean value, and in your settings.xml is:

```
<active>active</active>
```

You must to specify true to get the proxy config work:

```
<active>true</active>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read this [guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) in order to set proxies in settings.xml file. I can see that NTLM is not supported.

**Please note that currently NTLM proxies are not supported as they have not been tested. You may be able to use the relevant system properties on JDK 1.4+ to make this work.**

Comment: Thank you, I've Read the guide. The proxy configurered is **cntlm** and hides the ntlm stuff. The system sees a simple http(s) proxy. As I wrote, that proxy configuration is working for the first example, but is not working for the second. It stops when trying to download the "boot" stuff

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was solved using

```html
mvn package -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128
```

This change eventually forced the download from the repository. I'll always use these parameters for future maven activities!
Thanks everybody.